# php time validation without zero in hours

Tags: php, time

I want to validate for a 24 hour format.

The below code accepts 1:05:24 which is wrong, as it should instead only accept 01:05:24

```
try 
{  
  foreach ($arr as $key=>$item)
  {
    if (date('H:i:s', strtotime($item[1]))) 
    {

    } else {
      throw new Exception('Invalid Time Format');       
    }
  }
} 
catch (Exception $e) 
{
  echo $exp  = $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Consider using regexp

Answer (score 2):

The following use of [`preg_match`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) will differentiate between the two cases you have mentioned.

However, note that neither this nor the method that you mentioned in the question will correctly detect an invalid time such as `00:99:99`.

If you require that, you need a different method, the easiest of which is probably to parse out the numbers and run [this function](https://gist.github.com/toshimaru/3017096) on it.

```
<?php
$mydate_bad = "1:05:70";
$mydate_good = "01:05:24";
print (preg_match("/^\d\d:\d\d:\d\d$/", $mydate_bad));  # Returns 0
print (preg_match("/^\d\d:\d\d:\d\d$/", $mydate_good)); # Returns 1
?>
```

Comment: Of course, one could use `[0-5]` instead of `\d` for the first digit of the minute and seconds; and `([0-1][0-9])|(2[0-3])` instead of `\d\d` for the hour.  Also beware that, strictly speaking, one should escape the ``\`` characters for the string parser in order that the resulting regex is correct (but the PHP string parser happens to leave unescaped ``\`` characters in the result if the following character is insignificant, so this often goes unnoticed).

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you've provided, one way would be the following:

```
$php_date = date('H:i:s', strtotime($item[1]));
if ($php_date && $php_date == $item[1]) {
    // valid date
}
```

This will check that a date could be created as in your code, and it will also ensure that the resulting date in the format `H:i:s` corresponds to what the user entered.

However, in terms of user-friendliness, if you can create a date from the user input, it might be better just to accept it and add the leading 0 yourself if it is missing. Simply use `$php_date` in favor of `$item[1]` afterwards.